# get the synchronisation right

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, runtime-error

I did a little test, because I wanted to store an array (or some kind of list) that would be used by multiple threads at a time.

My Main-Class:

```
package main;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
private final static Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                Values.incrementValues();
            }
        }

    }, 1000, 1000);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                Values.addValue(0);
            }
        }

    }, 1000, 1000);

    Timer timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                Values.printValues();
            }
        }

    }, 1000, 1000);
}
}
```

And this is the Class I store the array in:
    package main;

```
public class Values {
static int[] values = new int[1];
private final static Object lock = new Object();

public static void incrementValues() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i]++;
        }
    }
}

public static void addValue(int e) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        int[] temp = values;
        values = new int[temp.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            values[i] = temp[i];
        }
        values[temp.length] = e;
    }
}

public static void printValues() {
    printValues(values);
}

public static void printValues(int[] values) {
    synchronized (lock) {
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int e : values) {
        sb.append(e);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
}
```

The output I should get is a row of numbers like: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

but instead I get 21 21 19 18 17 16 15 15 14 13 11 10 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 2 1 0

I think it must be directly in front of me, but I can't find it.

Comment: You should build the string builder within the synchronised block, not outside of it. Also depending on thread scheduling you may add 0 before the previous 0 has been incremented hence the duplicates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guarantee two threads to be executed in synchronized but do not guarantee the execution order.

So **incrementValues** and **addValue** will be in race condition. You have duplicate variables because **addValue** is sometimes executed before **incrementValues**.

If you want to guarantee sequential order without any duplicates you should implement a gate that will ensure **incrementValues** and **addValue** are executed in proper order.

BTW: I think that synchronized block in the Main class is unnecessary since you already do locking in the Values class.

Comment: The synchonized block in main is only there, because I thought it was a problem with synchronisation.
Thank you for your help!
I should hav thought about this!